# Trabalhando com dados recebidos por socket em C

Tags: c, c++, socket

Tenho um script que recebe dados via socket feito em C, e estou com dificuldades para trabalhar com esses dados.

Os dados recebidos do cliente: "imei:123123123,23123,tracker,0.0......".

Preciso receber esses dados e dar um tipo de explode a cada "," mesmo modelo usado pelo PHP.

O trecho do código onde estou com dificuldade...

```
while(client_size = recv(fd, msgin, sizeof(msgin), 0) != 0){

    //log
    myfile.open ("x.log",ios::app);
    myfile << put_time(localtime(&t), "%c") << " Data: " << msgin << endl;
    myfile.close();

    //------A intenção seria essa------------

    char *text = explode(msgin,',');
    .............
    ..........

    memset(msgin, 0, sizeof(msgin)); //Limpa o buffer
}
```

Como proceder??

Answer (score -1):

Utilize a função **strtok** da `<string.h>`. Ela quebra uma string em vários tokens, baseados em caracteres determinados.
Mais informações em: [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

Comment: Você quis dizer *strtok*?